# Remove onSubmit() method

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I found the following code in the internet and I want to know how can I remove the `onSubmit` method which is an button click and the code still working. When I simply remove the method the code is destroyed.

```
public class CellSignalStrength extends Activity{
    TextView tv;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.info);
    }
    public void onSubmit(View v) {
        TelephonyManager tm=(TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        int phoneType=tm.getPhoneType();
        String ptype="";
        switch(phoneType) {
            case TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_CDMA:
                ptype="\nPhone Type: CDMA\n";
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_GSM:
                ptype="\nPhone Type: GSM\n";
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_SIP:
                ptype="\nPhone Type: SIP\n";
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_NONE:
                ptype="\nPhone Type: NONE\n";
                break;
        }
        tv.setText(ptype);
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like `onSubmit()` coming from `onClick` in xml. So, removing it from both xml and java will do the trick. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: Yes,that exactly I want but when I remove the onSubmit what can I do with (View v) .I tried what you told me and there are many errors.

Comment: If you need those codes, just copy-paste the codes inside `onCreate()` method like the other answer which someone mentioned. Then you won't need the function.

Comment: Thank you,with that it works

Answer (score 0):

if you want to do what the onClick does without with, Just move the code inside

> onCreate

like this

```
public class CellSignalStrength extends Activity{
    TextView tv;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.info);
           TelephonyManager tm=(TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        int phoneType=tm.getPhoneType();
        String ptype="";
        switch(phoneType) {
            case TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_CDMA:
                ptype="\nPhone Type: CDMA\n";
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_GSM:
                ptype="\nPhone Type: GSM\n";
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_SIP:
                ptype="\nPhone Type: SIP\n";
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.PHONE_TYPE_NONE:
                ptype="\nPhone Type: NONE\n";
                break;
        }
        tv.setText(ptype);
    }
}
```